# msbuild refer to a env variable

Tags: c#, msbuild, environment-variables, msbuild-task

To automate a build, I use a props file with the name of a path env variable that may (or may not) be in the computer. (I hope I'll be able to add a condition later on)

My props file is like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyVersion>EnvVarPath</MyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I import that props file in my csproj file and use a copy task to copy a file trying to use $(MyVersion) like this:

```
  <Target Name="Copy1File" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="$(MyVersion)" Importance="high" />
    <Copy
      SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)File.xml"
      DestinationFolder="$(MyVersion)folder\File.xml"
    />
```

`MyVersion` var evaluates to "EnvVarPath" string but not the value of the env variable. I also tried using %EnvVarPath% in the props file, but it also evaluates to "%EnvVarPath%", (which can be copied to a file explorer and works), but does not evaluate as the path itself for msbuild.

How could I get that path value in my build?

Comment: Try to remove `<MyVersion>EnvVarPath</MyVersion>` because it actually overrides the varialbe value.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirSerykh, but if I remove it I can't automate the env version that I need to change every release, so unfortunately that is not an option

Comment: All enviromment variables are exposed as properties. So can't you just do `<MyVersion>$(EnvVarPath)</MyVersion>` or am I missing something? You could also pass args on command line `/p:MyVersion=%EnvVarPath%` if really necessary, but shouldn't be

Comment: Thanks pinkfloydx33. <MyVersion>xxxx</MyVersion>is the thing that I automate and change every version, so unfortunately I can't use the env variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As as been mentioned in the comments, all environment variables are automatically available as Properties - so `$(windir)` should give the path to the windows directory on windows systems.

Since this may not always be possible to use inline due to added indirection or environment variable names that aren't valid in MSBuild XML (e.g. `ProgramFiles(x86)`), the necessary static method on `System.Environment` has been whiteliested in MSBuild and can be used like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ProgramFilesVarPrefix>ProgramFiles</ProgramFilesVarPrefix>
  <ProgramFilesVarSuffix>(x86)</ProgramFilesVarSuffix>
  <ProgramFilesLocation>$([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('$(ProgramFilesVarPrefix)$(ProgramFilesVarSuffix)'))</ProgramFilesLocation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Evaluates to (as displayd in MSBuild Structured Log Viewer):
[image]